# There is no prenorm in $c_{\infty}$ generating the coordinatewise convergence

Tags: functional-analysis

The space $c_{\infty}$ is the space of coordinatewise convergence: $\xi ^{(n)}$ tends to $\xi$ if for every $k$ the sequence $\xi^{(n)}_k$ tends to $\xi_k$. So I need to prove that there  is no such prenorm for which every sequence converge in the announced sense iff it converges in the prenormed space. So I tried to use the sequence $\frac{p^n}{\Vert p^n \Vert}$ So it's limit in prenormed space should be equal to $1$. Therefore the pointwise limit should be $1$. Or pointwise limit of numerator is $\Vert p^n \Vert$, right? So far, it seems to me little bit strange, but still I can't find the contradiction

Comment: What is the vector space? That of all bounded complex sequences? All sequences converging to $0$? Or just the space of all complex sequences?

Comment: in the book it says that this is the space of all sequences

Comment: First note that this toplogy has unique limits, so that if it is generated by a semi-norm the semi-norm must already be a norm. Next let the vector $e_n$ be the sequence that is $1$ at term $n$ and $0$ else. Now the sequence $(x_n )_{n\in \Bbb N}$ with $x_n = \frac1{\|e_n\|}$ is in your space and you have that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{e_k}{\|e_k\|}$ converges pointwise to $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$. However that sum is not a Cauchy sequence, so it cannot converge wrt the norm. Contradiction, there is no norm.

Comment: The limit is unique, because semi-norm detects distinct points, and convergence is coordinatewise? So far the property that $p(x) \geqslant 0$ iff $x  = 0$ therefore the semi-norm is norm, right?

Comment: If you have $p(x)=0$ then the constant sequence of vectors $x$ converges not only to $x$ but also to $0$. Hence if a semi-norm is not a norm you must have that convergence is not unique.

Comment: Thank you! I got it.